# How to get date difference in days using hive

Tags: sql, date, hive, timestamp

```
SELECT USR_LOGINNAME,USR_EMAIL FROM USERS
  WHERE STATUS= 1    AND   
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,MODIFIED_DATE,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)=1;
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use `datediff(enddate, startdate)` function:

```
datediff(current_date, date(MODIFIED_DATE)) = 1
```

If enddate is less than startdate, the result is negative.

Answer (score 0):

If you want data from yesterday, I would instead suggest:

```
WHERE STATUS = 1 AND   
      MODIFIED_DATE < CURRENT_DATE AND
      MODIFIED_DATE >= DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, -1)
```

This allows Hive to use `MODIFIED_DATE` for optimization, such a partition pruning.